# Remove/Ignore specific missing field BibTeX warning

Tags: bibtex, warnings

I am compiling my reference list with BibTeX, where I must use some journal-specific bibliography style. Apparently, the latter requires the address field to be populated. In one specific instance, however, there is not a real publisher in some address, since the publications are simply available online (Proceedings of Machine Learning Research) and I cannot find any sensible address. Leaving the address-field empty gives me the warning

`BibTeX: empty address in [ref]`

Is there a way of removing such single specific BibTeX warnings somehow?

Comment: You could remove the warning by editing the `.bst` style, but since it is a publisher style and editing `.bst` styles is not always that simple, I'd probably not do that and just accept the warning. As long as the output is OK the warning is just a ... well warning that you can choose to ignore. Depending on the style it might be possible to silence the warning by giving a dummy value for the `address` field, but all dummy values I could think of have the potential to cause undesirable output in certain circumstances, so I cannot recommend that.

Comment: The database is helping you in case you got distracted while filling in the field. Since you did it on purpose, well ...

Comment: Thanks for your replys - tbh, this is not a very serious issue indeed. But this "1 warning" number showing up in Overleaf is just a distracting/annoying thorn in my flesh, since it could really be absent. So I was wondering, whether I can get rid of it, while learning something about BibTeX at the same time. Btw, a dummy value like \phantom or so indeed produces undesirable output. Seems difficult... I might go with making a minimal change of the `.bst` though... What would I need to change exactly?

Comment: Related to my last question: I deleted the line `address "address" output.check` from the `FUNCTION {inproceedings}` in the `.bst` file, which seems to be an acceptable solution for me, looking at my otherwise more or less finished reference list. While there might also be the possibility to only remove the warning from `output.check` in this case instead of the whole address field, this might really start to turn into overkill.

Comment: Probably online journals still have real publishers that should have real addresses. At first glance that of PMLR seems to be now ML Research Press from the Maastricht, University, although in the  ISSN appear Cambridge (maybe because the publisher in  the organizer of each conference, then  changing  every  year, or so ...no idea, really).

Comment: Just a `\mbox{}`  in the address field should  be enough to remove the warning, without add anything to  the reference,  but probably the style add automatically a ending dot or  comma after the non-empty addresses.